# capture specific WebView element to an image format?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

android.webkit.WebView has [capturePicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#capturePicture%28%29)() to capture the entire contents of the current WebView, but how would you do this for only a specific element on the webpage? For example, you might have many images and text elements positioned with CSS in a `div`.There may be many elements but I would just like to capture the `div` as it is rendered in the WebView.

The only idea I came up with is to load just that `div` only as the entire HTML of another WebView and call `capturePicture`. The other question how to take a `Picture` object to a format that can be used with the iText library (PNG, JPEG, GIF). Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

(A function of my app is to output PDF documents. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` to capture the view as image. and then you have to create a method to do that. and here is my saving method

```
    void Save() {
    if (null != view.getDrawable()) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        save = view.getDrawingCache();
        final File myDir = new File(folder);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        final Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
          file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                    "Something Went Wrong check if you have Enough Memory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        final Toast tst = Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                "Please Select An Image First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();
    }
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: In above answer, where is the idea of capturing DIV element to create image? Is this to make fool?

Comment: @YuDroid.  View.getDrawingCache() it actually capture the view. As an image. Follow my answer above. And are you kidding me??

Comment: But as per question "There may be many elements but I would just like to capture the div as it is rendered in the WebView.", how are you getting specific element? This is my question. Capturing an image from  view is straight forward just like other Views. Moreover, when my screen comes in landscape mode, I am not getting full height of WebView, i.e. getContentHeight() is not returning full HTML height. How to deal with this?

Comment: in this case i suggest you to re-think about using webview, if your intention is to load images only.